# Can't install icon theme KDE plasma 5

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, themes, icons, kde

I have been trying to install a icon theme. The problem is when selecting the achieve or the index I get `The file is not a valid icon theme archive.` both of these [1](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Super+flat+remix+icon+theme?content=169073) and [2](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Square-Beam+KDE?content=165154) should work but they do not none of the half dozen I have tried from kde look and one from gnome look work how do I install them. I am new to kde.